# Java Calculating all potential palindromes

Tags: java, string, palindrome

I'm trying to come up with an algorithm for calculating the number of palindromes of different strings formed out of the characters of a **parent** string

Right now I'm using the following to test if the string generated is a palindrome:

```
public static Boolean isPalindrome(String s) 
{
    int n = s.length();
    for (int i=0;i<(n / 2);++i) 
    {
        if (s.charAt(i) != s.charAt(n - i - 1)) 
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```

Which is working properly, however any attempt I've made to create a palindrome is not working the way I'd like. Basically I want to take a word like **racecar** and come up with all *palindromes* that are possible with any combination of any char in the string as long as it's a palindrome. So for example, with racecar of course racecar would work as well as aaacaaa or even eecrcee. I've been futile in my attempts, has anyone ever tried generating palindromes based off of a string with these constraints?

Comment: If you just want the number of palindromes, you can compute it mathematically. For instance, in your "racecar" example, there are 4*4*4*4 = 256 possible palindromes of length 7 using the letters [a,c,e,r].

Comment: Show us your attempt, and we'll help you figure out what you're doing wrong. As your question currently is, you're asking us to write the code for you, and that's off-topic for StackOverflow. See [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Any reason you’re returning a Boolean with capital B? boolean with small b would be the norm.

Comment: Does the generated palindrom have to be the same length as the original? For racecar, would crarc and aaaccceeecccaaa work? If they can be any length, there will of course be infinitely many.

Comment: When I enter `algorithm generate combination` in my seach engine, interesting things come up. Try the same.

Comment: @friendlydog That's much easier, what the formula is the number of unique characters squared?

Comment: Number of unique letters raised to the power of (n + 1) / 2, if I’m not mistaken.

Comment: @OleV.V. this is exactly what I was looking for awesome thank you! I just created an algorithm in my program based off of this math formula and it works perfectly (for odd numbers need to do (N + 1) / 2 when even numbers work with just N / 2). Thank you so much!

Comment: It doesn’t hurt to do (n + 1) / 2 for all numbers. For even numbers, the remainder (1) will just be discarded in the integer division, and the result will be the same as n / 2. Slightly tricky, I admit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The number of possible palindromes depends on how many characters you can choose from, and how long the word has to be.

In the "racecar" example, you have 4 unique letters to choose from, and you need to make a string of length 7. So there are 4 choices for the 1st character, 4 for the 2nd, 4 for the 3rd, 4 for the 4th (middle character). The 5th character must be the same as the 3rd, the 6th must be the same as the 2nd, and the 7th must be the same as 1st.

You only need to make a letter choice for half of the string (in this case, the first 4 letters), because in a palindrome the other half is a mirror image of the first half. So 4*4*4*4 possibilities in total for this example.

In general, it will be **`N^K`** (`Math.pow(N, K)`) possible palindromes, where **`N`** is the number of distinct letters you can choose from, and **`K`** is half the length of the string you need (add 1 if the string length is odd).

Comment: This is exactly what I was looking for awesome thank you! I just created an algorithm in my program based off of this math formula and it works perfectly (for odd numbers need to do (N + 1) / 2 when even numbers work with just N / 2). Thank you so much!